# An app to stop another app (Music Player) after some time

Tags: iphone, ios, music.app

A friend of mine asked this question "Do you know of any timer apps for iPhone which will close down a particular app after a set period of time?"

On questioning further - the "particular" app happened to be Music Player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Launch **Clock**
2. Choose **Timer**
3. Tap on **When Timer Ends**
4. Scroll right to the bottom and pick **Stop Playing**
5. Set your time - say, 20 minutes (or whatever time you want) and tap on **Start**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is fantastic!

Comment: @DavidPearce: Glad could be of help!